# Android Bug: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path in android

Tags: android, json, serialization

This is my JSON

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "media":{
            "name":"ABC",
            "url":"abc.org/"
        },
        "published":"2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z",
        "_links":{
            "self":{
                "href":"acb.net"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Class ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiServiceInterface {
@GET("/api/feed/channels/current/entries")
ApiFeedCurrentRequest getAllApiFeedCurrent();
}
```

Class ApiFeedCurrentRequest

```
public class ApiFeedCurrentRequest {
@SerializedName("id")
private int mId;
@SerializedName("media")
private Media mMedia;
@SerializedName("published")
private String mPublished;
@SerializedName("_links")
private Link mLinks;
```

Class ApiService

```
private static final String TAG = "__API__Service";
private final ApiServiceInterface mApiService;
public ApiService(Context context) {
    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .create();
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constant.BASE_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
            .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
            .setLog(new AndroidLog(TAG))
            .setConverter(new CleanGsonConverter(gson))
            .setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler(context))
            .build();
    this.mApiService = restAdapter.create(ApiServiceInterface.class);
}

public ApiFeedCurrentRequest getAllData() {
    if (mApiService != null) {
        return mApiService.getAllApiFeedCurrent();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

Class CleanGsonConverter

    public class CleanGsonConverter extends GsonConverter {

    private Gson mGson;

    public CleanGsonConverter(Gson gson) {
        super(gson);
        mGson = gson;
    }

    public CleanGsonConverter(Gson gson, String encoding) {
        super(gson, encoding);
        mGson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
        boolean willCloseStream = false; // try to close the stream, if there is no exception thrown using tolerant  JsonReader
        try {
            String mDirty = toString(body);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mDirty)) return null;
            String clean = mDirty.replaceAll("(^\\(|\\)$)", "");
            body = new JsonTypedInput(clean.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(body.in()));
            jsonReader.setLenient(true);
            Object o = mGson.fromJson(jsonReader, type);
            willCloseStream = true;
            return o;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (willCloseStream) {
                closeStream(body);
            }
        }
    }

private String toString(TypedInput body) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(body.in()));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

private void closeStream(TypedInput body) {
    try {
            InputStream in = body.in();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In Activity.

```
private class GetDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private WeakReference<SplashActivity> mWeakReference;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;
    private boolean mErrorInternet = false;
    private ApiFeedCurrentRequest mApiFeedCurrent;
    public GetDataAsync(SplashActivity splashActivity) {
        mWeakReference = new WeakReference<SplashActivity>(splashActivity);
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(splashActivity);
        mDialog.setMessage(splashActivity.getString(R.string.message_loading));
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        SplashActivity activity = mWeakReference.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            if (Utils.isInternetAvailable()) {
                try {
                    mApiFeedCurrent = activity.mApiService.getAllData();
                } catch (RetrofitError error) {
                    DebugTool.logD("ERROR = " + error.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                mErrorInternet = true;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my Error.

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
                                                                          at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
                                                                          at com.seesaa.newsaudiocast.api.CleanGsonConverter.fromBody(CleanGsonConverter.java:60)
                                                                          at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:367)
                                                                          at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
                                                                          at $Proxy0.getAllApiFeedCurrent(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.seesaa.newsaudiocast.api.ApiService.getAllData(ApiService.java:50)
                                                                          at com.seesaa.newsaudiocast.activity.SplashActivity$GetDataAsync.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:75)
                                                                          at com.seesaa.newsaudiocast.activity.SplashActivity$GetDataAsync.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:49)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
```

Please. Help me fix bug. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Class ApiInterface**

```
public interface ApiServiceInterface {
  @GET("/api/feed/channels/current/entries")
  ApiFeedCurrentRequest getAllApiFeedCurrent();
}
```

> replace with

```
    public interface ApiServiceInterface {
     @GET("/api/feed/channels/current/entries")
     List<ApiFeedCurrentRequest> getAllApiFeedCurrent();
    }
```

AND :in Activity

```
private List<ApiFeedCurrentRequest> mApiFeedCurrent = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            SplashActivity activity = mWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                if (Utils.isInternetAvailable()) {
                    try {
                        mApiFeedCurrent = activity.mApiService.getAllData();
                    } catch (RetrofitError error) {
                        DebugTool.logD("ERROR = " + error.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    mErrorInternet = true;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Hope it will help you my friend ! :)

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
ApiFeedCurrentRequest getAllApiFeedCurrent();
```

to this
    ApiFeedCurrentRequest[] getAllApiFeedCurrent();

or

```
List<ApiFeedCurrentRequest> getAllApiFeedCurrent();
```

Comment: Yes. It will try it! Thanks you very much!